# Although the solc [solidity compiler] package is installed still it shows the error Could not find a declaration file for module 'solc'

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, blockchain, solidity

Although the solc [solidity compiler] package is installed still it shows the error Could not find a declaration file for module 'solc'.

here is the compile.js file

```
const path = require("path");
const solc = require("solc");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const campaignPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Campaign.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath, "utf8");
const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for (let contract in output) {
  fs.outputJsonSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, contract.replace(":", "") + ".json"),
    output[contract]
  );
}
```

when i try to run node compile.js it shows me the following error:

```
node:assert:399
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Invalid callback object specified.
    at runWithCallbacks (C:\Users\devip\Desktop\ggtest\campaign\node_modules\solc\bindings\compile.js:120:30)
    at Object.boundFunctionStandard [as compileStandard] (C:\Users\devip\Desktop\ggtest\campaign\node_modules\solc\bindings\compile.js:83:20)
    at compileStandardWrapper (C:\Users\devip\Desktop\ggtest\campaign\node_modules\solc\wrapper.js:66:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\devip\Desktop\ggtest\campaign\ethereum\compile.js:10:21)        
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

Here is the package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "campaign",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "fs-extra": "^11.2.0",
    "ganache": "^7.9.2",
    "mocha": "^10.2.0",
    "solc": "^0.8.18",
    "web3": "^4.4.0"
  }
}
```

Although the solc package is already install i cannot get it to run successfully.

I have tried reinstalling the solc package and also tried to re-add node modules still its all futile